# How to communicate with the app from a Flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In a Flutter integration test, I would like to communicate with the application in the middle of a test, in order to trigger some arbitrary code to simulate a scenario. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: To pass around strings, have a look at: https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/mocking-integration-tests-with-flutter-af3b6ba846c7